# ValueError with converting list to ints

Tags: python

In the below function I am comparing a list (chdnalist) which depending on the txt file contains 3 ints.  In my test case 4,1,5.  Dnalist is a list of lists that was created from a csv file.  It contains name, and the dna of DNA strings that I use to create the ints in chdnalist as the first line and the subsequent lines are a name and 3 ints I need to compare to.  I am getting a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AGACT'`.  Im guessing it's trying to convert those strings in line 0 and can't.  How can I get it to skip line 0?  Ive tried continue and next with no success.  Or maybe as I'm very new at python I'm missing something entirely.

Here is a copy of my entire code:

```
def main():

    # TODO: Check for command-line usage
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Missing Files!")
        sys.exit(1)
    # TODO: Read database file into a variable
    dnalist = []
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r", newline = '') as subject_file:
        dnalst = csv.reader(subject_file)
        for row_list in dnalst:
            dnalist.append(row_list)

    # TODO: Read DNA sequence file into a variable
    with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as f:
        sequence = f.read()

    # TODO: Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence
    chdnalist = [[],[],[]]
    subsequence = [[],[],[]]
    for q in range(1, len(dnalist[0])):
        subsequence[q - 1] = dnalist[0][q]
    for t in range (len(subsequence)):
        chdnalist[t] = longest_match(sequence, subsequence[t])


    # TODO: Check database for matching profiles
    compare(dnalist, chdnalist)
    return

def longest_match(sequence, subsequence):
    """Returns length of longest run of subsequence in sequence."""

    # Initialize variables
    longest_run = 0
    subsequence_length = len(subsequence)
    sequence_length = len(sequence)


    # Check each character in sequence for most consecutive runs of subsequence
    for i in range(sequence_length - 1):

        # Initialize count of consecutive runs
        count = 0

        # Check for a subsequence match in a "substring" (a subset of characters) within sequence
        # If a match, move substring to next potential match in sequence
        # Continue moving substring and checking for matches until out of consecutive matches
        while True:

            # Adjust substring start and end
            start = i + count * subsequence_length
            end = start + subsequence_length

            # If there is a match in the substring
            if sequence[start:end] == subsequence:
                count += 1

            # If there is no match in the substring
            else:
                break

        # Update most consecutive matches found
        longest_run = max(longest_run, count)

    # After checking for runs at each character in seqeuence, return 
    longest run found
    return longest_run

    def compare(dnalist, chdnalist):
        for name, *dna in dnalist:
            dna = list(map(int, dna))
            if dna == chdnalist:
               print(name)
               return
        print("No match")

main()
```

Comment: Show us how you are reading the CSV file.

Comment: Please show the code that creates `dnalist`.

Comment: I can't say I approve of your variable naming conventions.

Comment: I use the header row later in the program to create chdnalist.  As I have other csv files, I use that as they have a different number of strings in the header file.

Comment: Try `dna = list(map(int, dna[1:]))`. Or, if it's more line based, instead change the line above it to `for name, *dna in dnalist[1:]:`.

Comment: Thank you!! I've been working on this for over a week.  I had a 2 hour lecture on python and some other work to make the same programs I made in C in python before this.  This was my first python program from scratch.

Comment: Another way is to use `header = next(dnalist)` to read the header row into a separate variable before the loop.